# Flex and layers

Tags: apache-flex

Does flex application have control layer like service layer, dao (data access object layer)? Control layer permits to connect client side to the server side of the application. Please I need help and an answer to this question

Comment: Accessing data services overview: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Flex/4.0/AccessingData/WSbde04e3d3e6474c46c45e7b4120d413dc14-8000.html

Answer (score 2):

> Does flex application have control layer like service layer, dao (data
>   access object layer)?

ActionScript does not inherently have this.  The Flex Framework is primarily a UI Framework and does not have any of this built in.   There is no reason why you can't build your own service layer / DAO.  Usually in Flex applications; I have a set of service classes [and/or Value Objects/Beans/Data Objects] that communicate with a server side backend.

There are a lot of frameworks out there that can help facilitate this in various ways.  Swiz, RobotLegs, PureMVC, Parsley, and Mate are some.  Cairngorm is an older one and has fallen out of favor due to its perceived complexity.